# Error 1415 en MySQl al crear un trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

Buenas tardes, estoy tratando de crear un trigger de alerta por falta de productos, el cual me arroja el error:

> Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger.

Esta es la Query del trigger que intento crear

```
delimiter $
create trigger alerta
after update
on producto
for each row
begin
    declare _cod_prod int;
    declare _cantidad_actual int;
    declare _cantidad_anterior int;
    declare _cantidad_alerta int;
    set _cod_prod=(select cod_producto from inserted);
    set _cantidad_actual=(select cantidad from inserted where cod_producto=_cod_prod);
    set _cantidad_anterior=(select cantidad_anterior from inserted);
    set _cantidad_alerta=1;
    if(_cantidad_actual<=_cantidad_alerta) then
    begin
        update producto set cantidad=_cantidad_anterior where cod_producto=_cod_prod;
        select * from producto;
    end;
    else
    begin
        update producto set cantidad_anterior=_cantidad_actual where cod_producto=_cod_prod;
        select * from producto;
    end;
    end if;
end $

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1):

El error es bastante claro, no puedes retornar un `result set` en un trigger y es es lo que estás haciendo con `select * from producto;`. Quita esos dos `selects` y deberías solucionar este problema.

Por otro lado si la idea de retornar los registros de `producto` es para algún tipo de seguimiento, lo que sí podrías hacer es insertarlos en una tabla copia de la original para luego verificarlos.